How to change an field in SQL in a specified amount of time?
For context: My table is organized like this:

id
start
end
status

The current time can be entered (is is the default value), or the time the user prefers. The end time is set to always be two hours from the start time.
I would need the status to change from active to inactive when the current time passes the time that is in the end time field.
What would be the best way to do this?

Don’t. Instead your application logic should be able to determine this automatically. Sounds like both end and status can be derived from start.

The DB cannot do that for you, and it shouldn't. You can decide what the status should be at the time you SELECT the data based on the content of start without ever storing end and status, as @ChrisHaas mentioned. You should never store a value that can be determined at the time the data is used. It's a waste of storage on the server and can lead to erroneous values (something doesn't get updated when it should have been, leading to the value being inaccurate). Determining that value at the time it is needed eliminates that problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use a cron job or the MySQL Event Scheduler to periodically update the status field.
